# Fetch the data from Date and Time Calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, caml-query, camlviewfields

I am trying to fetch the result from list based on 3  conditions( Month Name,Employee,Department).

In my SharePoint List(Month Name is calculated column fetching month from column "Joining Date") .

Below is the caml query trying to get fetech the value using column(Month Name) but found no luck.I had gone through the internal of the column "Month Name" and I see "Month" as internal name

can any one help me in knowing what went wrong in below code

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Employee + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Department+ "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Month Name'/><Value Type='Calculated'>" + monthname+ "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>")
```

Comment: You can only nest two `Eq` directly in one `And` statement, so you need to add another `And` statement

Answer (score 0):

You can only nest two `Eq` directly in one `And` statement, so you need to add another `And` statement, like this:

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Employee + "</Value></Eq><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department'/><Value Type='Text'>" + Department+ "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Month Name'/><Value Type='Calculated'>" + monthname+ "</Value></Eq></And></And></Where></Query></View>")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I don't get the result.I am confused about the column name(Should i use the internal name for the column(Month Name) or use it's display name)I renamed the column to MonthName ,But found no luck .

Comment: You need to use internal name

Comment: Thanks for Response.but Found no luck